# Regular expression to match valid paths in a folder structure

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression to match all valid paths in a virtual folder structure?

Say I have a virtual folder structure represented by a string like this:

`foo/bar/baz`

Then the following strings should match:

- `foo` (and possibly `foo/`)
- `foo/bar` (and possibly `foo/bar/`)
- `foo/bar/baz` (and possibly `foo/bar/baz/`)

but these strings should NOT match:

- `foo/ba`
- `foo/bar/b`

Comment: /^yourstring(\/|$)/ should do it.

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match must match from start and either to a slash or to the end of sting.

This gives the following regex:

```
/^yourstring(\/|$)/
```

where '`yourstring`' can be:

```
foo
foo/bar
foo/bar/baz
etc
```

but not:

```
foo/b
foo/ba
etc
```

The string to test against is always the full path, like:

```
foo/bar/baz
```

Comment: Thanks, I use it in C# code like this: `var sql = $"SELECT * FROM documents WHERE groupname ~ '^{group}(\\/|$)'";`

Comment: Actually, I don't think it's necessary to escape the slash then (but it doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `^(\w+\/?)+$` pattern; `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

here is a demonstration in js

```js
function isValid(str){
  return /^(\w+\/?)+$/.test(str)
}

console.log(isValid("foo"))
console.log(isValid("foo/"))
console.log(isValid("for/bar/baz"))
console.log(isValid("for/bar/baz/"))
//invalid filenames
console.log(isValid("for/bar//"))
console.log(isValid("rdxrc/+"))
console.log(isValid(";/lllj/ii/"))
```